# modelr: cross-validated model fitting for all variables in a dataset that match criterion

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataset that contains a number of (factor) variables with the prefix "cat_".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)
library(lazyeval)
library(purrr)

# create the dataset
df_foo = wakefield::r_data_frame(
  n = 100,
  wakefield::r_series(wakefield::r_sample, j = 5, name = "cat"),
  Y = wakefield::normal()
)
```

I want to be able to compute the pairwise, k-fold cross-validated regression R2 of each of these factor variables with the response variable using the tidy framework.

It is easy to compute this across folds for a few variables as below.

```
df_foo %>% 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(as.factor), .cols = vars(starts_with("cat"))) %>% 
  crossv_kfold(k = 10, id = "id") %>% 
  mutate_(
    .dots = setNames(
      list(
        interp(
          quote(
            purrr::map_dbl(train, .f = function(train_data) {
          summary(stats::lm(Y ~ cat_1, data = train_data))$r.squared
        }))),
        interp(
          quote(
            purrr::map_dbl(train, .f = function(train_data) {
          summary(stats::lm(Y ~ cat_2, data = train_data))$r.squared
        })))
      ),
      nm = c("cat_1", "cat_2")
    )
  )
```

## Questions:

- How to generalize this to an arbitrary number of variables?
- Why do I explicitly have to use the namespace accessors for the functions `purrr::map_dbl` and `stats::lm` (the logic above will not work if I remove the namespace accessors)?

---

### Edit:

The following code gets the R2 for each of the variables, but it cannot be  flattened out to a number of columns equal to the number of variables in the dataset.

```
make_r2_variable = function(var_name, train_data) {
  summary(stats::lm(Y ~ var_name, data = train_data))$r.squared
}

make_r2 = function(train_data) {
  summarise_at(
    .tbl =  data.frame(train_data),
    .cols = vars(starts_with("cat_")),
    .funs = funs(make_r2_variable(., train_data = train_data))
  )

}

df_foo = df_foo %>% 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(as.factor), .cols = vars(starts_with("cat"))) %>% 
  crossv_kfold(k = 10, id = "id") %>% 
  mutate(
    R2 = map(.x = train, .f = make_r2)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I think is as compact as it can get is this:

```
make_r2_variable = function(var_name, train_data) {
  summary(stats::lm(Y ~ var_name, data = train_data))$r.squared
}

make_r2 = function(train_data) {
  summarise_at(
    .tbl =  data.frame(train_data),
    .cols = vars(starts_with("cat_")),
    .funs = funs(make_r2_variable(., train_data = train_data))
  )

}

df_foo = df_foo %>% 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(as.factor), .cols = vars(starts_with("cat"))) %>% 
  crossv_kfold(k = 10, id = "id") %>% 
  mutate(
    R2 = map(.x = train, .f = make_r2)
  ) %>% 
  unnest(R2)
```

This is basically the solution that I had in the edit plus `unnest`. This basically mutates the `S3: resample` column using `map` and within that it uses `mutate_at` to cycle over the columns that match the criterion. Since  that returns a list/1D `data.frame`, a call to `unnest` is required.